# When to use trig substitution?

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm trying to solve this physics equation:
$$E=\frac {\lambda y}  {4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \int_{-\frac l 2}^\frac l 2  \frac {dx} {({x^2+y^2})^\frac 3 2}  $$

However, my calculus is a little rusty and am told I need to do a trig substitution. My question is, when do we use trig substitution?

Comment: When you see a nice pair of squared terms inside a square root like $(x^2+y^2)^\frac 32$, that's a good time.  In particular, let $x=y\tan\theta,dx=y\sec^2\theta d\theta$...  The trigonometric identities like $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ are the basis for these substitutions since there are ways to rearrange so that a square root is removed from the problem leaving an easier problem to solve.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=y\tan\theta,$
$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{y}{\cos^2\theta}.$$
Hence, your definite integral will be
$$\begin{align}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{1}{(y^2\tan^2\theta+y^2)^{3/2}}\cdot\frac{y}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta&=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{1}{(y/\cos\theta)^3}\cdot\frac{y}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta\\&=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{\cos\theta}{y^2}d\theta\\&=\frac{1}{y^2}[\sin\theta]_{\alpha}^{\beta}\\&=\frac{\sin\beta-\sin\alpha}{y^2}\end{align}$$
where $$-\frac{l}{2}=y\tan\alpha,\ \ \ \frac{1}{2}=y\tan\beta.$$
Here, I used 
$$1+\tan^2\theta=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}.$$